# Message Passing Example From Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using the example from [the Google tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and finding it difficult to pass a simple message to the content script from the popup.

Can you provide some suggestions on how to pass a simple message and view it either in the console log or alert?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "msg-test",
  "description": "message test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
     "matches": ["http://*/*","http://www.site.com/*"],
     "js": ["content.js"],
     "run_at": "document_end"
  }],  

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*"
  ]  
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  port.postMessage({greeting:"hello"});
});
```

**content.js**

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"content"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
  if(message.greeting === "hello"){
    alert(message.greeting);
  }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
       alert("button 2 was clicked");
     }; 

    document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
        alert("button 1 was clicked");
     }; 


}
```

*Note: In this example the content script will fire when the page matches manifest.json and the alert box will show.

Comment: @aclave1 Could you please introduce all files of your extension in question, I want to try myself. The other files (such as popup.html) did not explicitly determined in developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, I wouldn't message pass between your popup and your content script. I would message pass between your [Background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) and your content scripts. Your popup page should only be used to show some ui to interact with your app.

With that being said, I will show you the way to pass messages between your background and your content script.

In your content script:

```
//This line opens up a long-lived connection to your background page.
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"mycontentscript"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
  if(message.greeting === "hello"){
    alert(message.greeting);
  }
});
```

In your background page(possibly your popup? but I don't recommend it)

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  port.postMessage({greeting:"hello"});
});
```

Here is the sequence of events that will take place:

1. Your application will inject your content script into the page
2. Your content script will open up a port to communicate with the background script.
3. Your background script will be notified that a port was open, allowing it to send a message to it, or attach a message listener to it.

In the background script or the content script, you can listen for messages by using `port.onMessage.addListener()`. provided that port is in scope. Using ports is much easier to grasp and allows for simple, two way communication!

Edit:

If you would like to pass messages to your background page from your popup script, use the exact same method:

```
var port   =   chrome.runtime.connect({name: "popup-port"});
port.postMessage({status:"poppedup"});
```

Edit 2:

To navigate your user to a new page, do this:

```
function navigateToPage(url){
    chrome.tabs.query({url: url}, function(tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        return tab ? chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active:true}) : chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
    });
}
});
```

What this function does is, it checks to see if there is a tab with the url you want to go to, if there is, switch to it, else, create a tab with that url and navigate to it.

Comment: popup.js is considered a "Dumb view": 

"In a typical extension with a background page, the UI — for example, the browser action or page action and any options page — is implemented by dumb views. When the view needs some state, it requests the state from the background page. When the background page notices a state change, the background page tells the views to update."

Comment: You can add a background page by adding this to your manifest:  
"background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": true
    },

Comment: No, but that's not message passing. You don't even need a content script to change the url of the current tab. I will edit my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: After spending 2 hours fruitlessly looking through the official docs, THIS actually helps me accomplish what I wanted to.  THANK YOU